# amqp and camel error: route has no input

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, amqp, spring-amqp

I'm having some problems with my rout with Camel. This is my configuration file, very simple:

```
<bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://10.211.55.20:5672"/>
</bean>

<camel:camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

    <jmxAgent id="agent" createConnector="false" disabled="true"/>

    <camel:route>
        <route>
            <from uri="activemq:hello?destination.consumer.exclusive=true&amp;destination.consumer.prefetchSize=50"/>
            <to uri="stream:out"/>
        </route>
    </camel:route>
</camel:camelContext>
```

In this case there I'm using RabbitMQ and hello is the queue name.

Running it, I get this error message:

```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:  Route has no inputs: Route[[] -> [Route[[From[activemq:hello?destination.consumer.exclusive=true&destination.consumer.prefetchSize=50]] -> [To[stream:out]]]]]
```

Any idea? Where can I get a sample or a tutorial for Camel + RabbitMQ ?

--- UPDATED ---

Following the suggestion on below comment, I fixed the configuration and a little step ahead has been done. Now it's seem to be able to connect to queue but, if I try to write I get "camelContext must be specified" exception

```
<bean id="messageConverter" class="amqp.spring.converter.XStreamConverter"/>

<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory" host="10.211.55.20" port="5672" />
<rabbit:template id="amqpTemplate" connection-factory="connectionFactory" message-converter="messageConverter" exchange="amq.fanout" />
<rabbit:admin connection-factory="connectionFactory"/>
<rabbit:queue name="hello"  />

<camel:camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <camel:route>
        <camel:from uri="file:src/data?noop=true" />
        <camel:log message="Log!"/>
        <camel:to uri="spring-amqp:amq.fanout:hello"/>
    </camel:route>
</camel:camelContext>
```

thanks,
Andrea

Comment: Just a quick question. Are you talking about Camel + RabbitMQ or Camel + ActiveMQ?

Comment: I'm trying to user Camel + RabbitMQ

Comment: The ActiveMQ component in Camel could not be used to connect to RabbitMQ, as they speak different protocol. For RabbitMQ, you should use the AMQP component.

Comment: the no input could be related to not having all the needed JARs on the classpath.

Comment: @RaymondTau thanks, I used spring-amqp and I'm getting an error related to "close" queue when I try to read and I get a "camelContext must be specified" when I try to write. I'm starting the application using mvn camel:run

Answer (score 0):

There are two error. First, the XML seems to be missing namespaces on the route:

```
<camel:route>
   <route>
        <from uri="activemq:hello?destination.consumer.exclusive=true&amp;destination.consumer.prefetchSize=50"/>
        <to uri="stream:out"/>
    </route>
```

Should be:

```
<camel:route>
   <camel:route>
        <camel:from uri="activemq:hello?destination.consumer.exclusive=true&amp;destination.consumer.prefetchSize=50"/>
        <camel:to uri="stream:out"/>
    </camel:route>
```

Then, RabbitMQ is not really compatible with ActiveMQ at the moment. Version 5.8 of ActiveMQ seems to support the AMQP protocol which RabbitMQ uses, but if it will be supported in the Camel component or if it will be compatible with RabbitMQ is another question. I don't know.

There is an AMQP component in Camel as well. It's using the Apache QPID client and I have not had any luck running it with RabbitMQ. It might work to some extent if you dig deep down in using the some speific versions etc. (http://www.rabbitmq.com/interoperability.html).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It turned out that I had stacked the `route`s.
So, instead of having

```
<camel:route>
   <route>
        <from uri="activemq:hello?destination.consumer.exclusive=true&amp;destination.consumer.prefetchSize=50"/>
        <to uri="stream:out"/>
    </route>
```

Just skip the enclosing `<route>`.